# Convert Spark SQL Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I'm current using a Databricks notebook, intially in Scala, using JDBC to connect to a SQL server and return a table.

i use the following code to query and display the table within the notebook

```
val ViewSQLTable= spark.read.jdbc(jdbcURL, "api.meter_asset_enquiry", connectionProperties)

display(ViewSQLTable)
```

Works great, however i want to be able to load the table into a pandas dataframe so i can take advantage of PandasProfing

I've tried the following but i seem to be missing something, from what i can tel the code above just displays whats return from the query but its not something that can be called?

here is what i tried in a new cell

```
%python
pandasDF = ViewSQLTable.select("*").toPandas()
print(pandasDF)
```

I'm assuming its a spark SQL table as when i run the first piece of code i get the following response

"ViewSQLTable: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: int, column2: int ... 49 more fields]"

anyone know how to load this table into a pandas dataframe using python?

Comment: which databricks are you using azure or aws?

Comment: I think you don't need the `.select(*)`, but just `ViewSQLTable.toPandas()`

Comment: Azure Databricks

Comment: This returns the following Error
`NameError: name 'ViewSQLTable' is not defined`

Comment: @teelove, The first code which you are creating spark dataframe, is that a scala code?

Comment: You can use ```%scala``` In Python Cell  and you can then use ```spark.table()``` to access table and you can then use ```toPandas()```

Comment: yes @Rakesh Govindula scala code to start with

Comment: The name ViewSQLTable is a scala variable probably of type spark.DataFrame.  The toPandas() is specific to Python.  I would write the dataframe from the api call to disk (file).  Then read up as a DataFrame, convert to Pandas, and use Pandas Profiling.  If you want you can try saving to temporary table.  Then read from temporary table.

Comment: Adrien Riaux - While you can convert to Pandas directly in scala.  I did not think the package - https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/ - is supported.  It is a PyPi distro.  Also, why can't the JDBC driver be called directly from Python.  Eliminating cross language notebook code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to explain more.  The variable in Scala are not directly accessible to Python.  Thus write from scala to file and read from file to Python DF is one path.  Hive tables (temporary) is another.

[image]

This shows x is not available to python.

Lets try with dataframes.

[image]

I now have a temporary view.

[image]

Again, df in the scala namespace is different then df in python.  However, the hive catalog and/or temporary views are accessible from all languages.

[image]

In short, be careful when mixing languages.  Variables do not get passed.

Comment: This was explained very well, thank you - i'm quite new to Databricks and this answer has helped some of my confusion, thank you